# send data beteen form qt5

Tags: c++, forms, qt5, qstring

I want to send data from  from to another one

I'm new in qt i googled my problem and find many solution
but no one focused one qstring value

login.cpp

```
void Login::GetSerial()
{
    QString s1 = cmd("WMIC cpu get ProcessorId");
    s1 = s1.replace("ProcessorId","");
    s1= s1.simplified();
    s1.replace(" ","");
    QString r1 = cmd("WMIC BaseBoard get serialnumber");
    r1 = r1.replace("SerialNumber","");
    r1= r1.simplified();
    r1.replace(" ","");
    QString text = s1;
    QString key = r1;
    QByteArray text_bin;
    text_bin = QByteArray::fromHex(text.toUtf8());
     QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-16");
     QTextEncoder *encoder = codec->makeEncoder(QTextCodec::IgnoreHeader);
    text_bin = encoder->fromUnicode(text);
    text_bin = text.toLocal8Bit();
    QByteArray key_bin = key.toUtf8();
    QByteArray decrypted = aes->decrypt(text_bin, key_bin, nullptr);
    QString s = decrypted.toHex();
    int x = s.size();
    QString r = s.remove(12,x);
    r = r.toUpper();
    ui->LblSn->setText("SN : " + r);//qstring r is the value i want to sent it to second
    
}
```

i want to put value from form1 in qlabel in second form
this is second form

register.cpp

```
Register::Register(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Register)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QRegExp rx(EMAIL_RX);
    QRegExpValidator *vali = new QRegExpValidator(rx,this);
    ui->Txtemail->setValidator(vali);
}

Register::~Register()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Register::on_BtnLogin_clicked()
{
   Login *l = new Login();
   l->show();
   hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is worked for me

```
QString Seria;

    void Login::setLabelT(const QString& title)
    {
        ui->LblSn->setText(title);
    }
    void Login::GetSerial()
    {
        QString s1 = cmd("WMIC cpu get ProcessorId");
        s1 = s1.replace("ProcessorId","");
        s1= s1.simplified();
        s1.replace(" ","");
        QString r1 = cmd("WMIC BaseBoard get serialnumber");
        r1 = r1.replace("SerialNumber","");
        r1= r1.simplified();
        r1.replace(" ","");
        QString text = s1;
        QString key = r1;
        QByteArray text_bin;
        text_bin = QByteArray::fromHex(text.toUtf8());
         QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-16");
         QTextEncoder *encoder = codec->makeEncoder(QTextCodec::IgnoreHeader);
        text_bin = encoder->fromUnicode(text);
        text_bin = text.toLocal8Bit();
        QByteArray key_bin = key.toUtf8();
        QByteArray decrypted = aes->decrypt(text_bin, key_bin, nullptr);
        QString s = decrypted.toHex();
        int x = s.size();
        QString r = s.remove(12,x);
        r = r.toUpper();
        ui->LblSn->setText("SN : " + r);
        Seria = "SN : " + r;
    }
```

register.cpp

```
void Register::setLabelTitle(const QString& title)
{
    ui->LblSnR->setText(title);    
}
```